Can I use Github to store update files for my python project?
I want to know if I can store my python program on a github (including the .exe) repo. From the other versions of the program running on different devices would simply download the update from the repo.
I'm pretty inexperienced with git and don't know the limits to what I can do with it
If I can't what other methods can I use to achieve my goal?

Is this what you're looking for? Hosting executable on github
